# React Native NavigationHeader.BackButton.Color

Tags: react-native

Im trying to change the back button for the `NavigationHeader.BackButton` but I don't see any way that is possible.

The header is rendered using the following...

```
_renderHeader(props,backAction){
    return (
            <NavigationHeader
            {...props}
            renderLeftComponent={props => this._renderLeftComponent(props,backAction)}
        />
    )
}

_renderLeftComponent(props,backAction){
    return (
        <NavigationHeader.BackButton
            onPress={backAction}
            onNavigate={backAction}
        />
    );
}
```

I have tried setting `tintColor` and `color` style but it doesn't work. I looked at the source code, but I don't see any way this can be done. Is there a way to either set the tint/color or to provide my own image?

Answer (score 0):

I am using [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) which allows you to choose from several different collections, including Google's [Material icons](https://design.google.com/icons/). The library provides you with an `Icon` component that you can integrate with several existing components, including `TabBarIOS`, `NavigatorIOS`, `Navigator.NavigationBar`, `ToolbarAndroid`, etc.

In addition it provides `Icon.Button` a convenient way of creating a button with a left icon, and of course you can simply use the Icon inline like this:

```
<Icon name='arrow-back' size={24} color={#900}/>
```

They have a pretty good documentation on their Github repo, have a look.